# convert strings column to hours

Tags: pandas, string

So I have a df like this (about 55 columns and four thousand rows, here just a sample):

```
0                                 opc18
1                                 opc14
2                                 opc16
3                                 opc15
4                                 opc13
5                                 opc14
6                                 opc16
7                                 opc17
8                                 opc15
9                                 opc15
10                                opc14
11                                opc15
12                                opc15
13                                opc14
14                                opc11
15                                opc17
16                                opc15
17                                opc17
18                                opc16
19                                opc17
20                                opc17
```

"opcX" is a string that goes from:

```
opc1 = 0:00
opc2 = 0:30
opc3 = 1:00
```

and so on up until:

```
opc48 = 23:30
```

my question is: how can I make all that column into a time format?
I could do one by one, of course, something like (assuming the column is called 'opc'):

```
for i in df.iloc[i,1]: 

'opc1' == 0:00
'opc2' == 0:30
```

and so on, but this is very tiresome. What I want is something like:

```
0  3:30
1  2:00
2  12:30
4  21:30
5  20:30
```

and the like

Is there a more compact and precise way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a map `obj` with opc1~opc48 to a time.

then apply it to row df

```
obj = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2021-02-10', '2021-02-10 23:59:59', freq='30T'),
               index=('opc' + pd.Series(np.arange(1, 49)).map(str))).dt.strftime('%H:%M')

obj.head()

    opc1    00:00
    opc2    00:30
    opc3    01:00
    opc4    01:30
    opc5    02:00
    dtype: object

df['opc'].map(obj)
```

---

output:

```
df['Time'] = df['opc'].map(obj)
print(df)

     opc   Time
0   opc18  08:30
1   opc14  06:30
2   opc16  07:30
3   opc15  07:00
4   opc13  06:00
5   opc14  06:30
6   opc16  07:30
7   opc17  08:00
8   opc15  07:00
9   opc15  07:00
10  opc14  06:30
11  opc15  07:00
12  opc15  07:00
13  opc14  06:30
14  opc11  05:00
15  opc17  08:00
16  opc15  07:00
17  opc17  08:00
18  opc16  07:30
19  opc17  08:00
20  opc17  08:00
```

Comment: This done perfectly fine the job. I didn't knew you could concatenate 'opc' with a number, Not sure what map('str') does then, but i'll look for it. Thank you!

Comment: `df['opc'].map(obj)` eq `df['opc'].map(lambda x: obj[x])`, like get a value with dict's key.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.Timedelta` with `pandas.Series.str.extract`:

```
t = pd.Timedelta("30m")
df["col"].str.extract("(\d+)", expand=False).astype(int).sub(1) * t
```

Output:

```
0    0 days 08:30:00
1    0 days 06:30:00
2    0 days 07:30:00
3    0 days 07:00:00
4    0 days 06:00:00
5    0 days 06:30:00
6    0 days 07:30:00
7    0 days 08:00:00
8    0 days 07:00:00
9    0 days 07:00:00
10   0 days 06:30:00
11   0 days 07:00:00
12   0 days 07:00:00
13   0 days 06:30:00
14   0 days 05:00:00
15   0 days 08:00:00
16   0 days 07:00:00
17   0 days 08:00:00
18   0 days 07:30:00
19   0 days 08:00:00
20   0 days 08:00:00
Name: col, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you. Days are not needed, but it worked.